# image onload function not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have written a basic turn-based combat game which works really well in chrome and firefox. However, it doesn't load any images in internet explorer despite all the other code working flawlessly. I have narrowed it down to a problem with my image onload function. Here is the code snippet in question:

```
// image load functions

function loadSpriteSheet() {
    gv.spriteSheet = new Image();
    gv.spriteSheet.src = 'Sprite Sheet v5.png';
}

function loadGUI() {
    gv.GUI = new Image();
    gv.GUI.src = 'gui.png';
}

function loadBackgrounds() {
    gv.backgrounds = new Image();
    gv.backgrounds.src = 'backgrounds.png';
}

// drawing functions

function drawArenaFloor() {
    // bunch of code to draw the floor of the arena in tiles

}

function drawUnderlay() {
    // bunch of code to draw stuff like player selector box

}

function drawArenaWalls() {
    // bunch of code to draw the walls of the arena in tiles

}

// main code body here


// this is the 'problem' function
function resizeCanvas() {
    // runs each time the DOM window resize event fires. resets the canvas dimensions to match window, then draws the new borders accordingly

    // bunch of code here to determine screen size, arena size etc.

    // load all the images for the game
    loadBackgrounds();
    loadSpriteSheet();
    loadGUI();

    // this is the 'problem' code
    gv.spriteSheet.onload = function() {
        drawArenaFloor();
        drawUnderlay();
        drawArenaWalls();
    }
}
```

Now here's the funny thing. If I remove the onload handler the images *sometimes* load in IE, but *never* load in chrome/firefox:

```
    // this is the 'problem' code, revised to *sometimes* work in IE (basically by commenting out the onload handler)
    // gv.spriteSheet.onload = function() {
        drawArenaFloor();
        drawUnderlay();
        drawArenaWalls();
    // }
```

This one really has me stumped. Any ideas?

Here is the full HTML source as requested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Copyright 2013-2014 -->

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Arena</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="Top section">
        <canvas id="shopButtonCanvas" class = "topButton"></canvas>
        <input type="button" alt="Shop" id="Shop button" class="topButton" onclick="shop()">
    <div>
        <p id="Display size">XxY, A/R</p>
    </div>
    <div id = "Ad container" class="xxx" onclick="clickOnAd()">
    </div>
        <canvas id="closeButtonCanvas" class = "topButton"></canvas>
        <input type="button" alt="Close" id="Close button" class="topButton" onclick="closeButton()">
</div>

<div id = "Main" align="center">
    <canvas id="Arena floor"></canvas>
    <canvas id="Underlay"></canvas>
    <canvas id="Arena walls"></canvas>
    <canvas id="Arena">Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.</canvas>
    <div id="Status bars" align="left">

        <canvas id="detailButtonCanvas" class="button"></canvas>
        <input type="button" alt="Player Detail" id="Detail button" class="button" onclick="detailButton()">

        <canvas id="Player health bar"></canvas>

        <div id="Round counter">
        <div id="Round display">
            <span><b>Round: </b><span id="Current round"></span> / <span id="Max rounds"></span></span>
        </div>

        <div id="Turn display">
            <span id="Turn outer"><b>Turn: </b></span><span id="Turn" class="player"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="Turn arrow"></div>

        </div>

        <canvas id="enemyDetailButtonCanvas" class="button"></canvas>
        <input type="button" alt="Enemy Detail" id="Enemy detail button" class="button" onclick="detailButton()">

    </div>

    <div id="Player stats">
                <h3 id="Player team name"><u>Player Team Stats</u></h3>
                <b>Players: </b><span id="Player living pieces"></span>
                <br> <b>Health: </b><span id="Player team health"></span>
                <br> <b>Stamina: </b><span id="Player team stamina"></span>
                <br> <b>Moves: </b><span id="Player team moves"></span>

                <h3 id="Player name"><u>Player Stats</u></h3>
                <b>Level: </b><span id="Player level"></span>
                <br> <b>Health: </b><span id="Player health"></span>
                <br> <b>Stamina: </b><span id="Player stamina"></span>
                <br> <b>Armor: </b><span id="Player AC"></span>
                <br> <b>Weapon: </b><span id="Player weapon"></span>
                <br> <b>Action: </b><span id="Player action"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="Enemy stats">
                <h3 id="Enemy team name"><u>Enemy Team Stats</u></h3>
                <b>Enemies: </b><span id="Enemy living pieces"></span>
                <br> <b>Health: </b><span id="Enemy team health"></span>
                <br> <b>Stamina: </b><span id="Enemy team stamina"></span>
                <br> <b>Moves: </b><span id="Enemy team moves"></span>

                <h3 id="Enemy name"><u>Enemy Stats</u></h3>
                <b>Level: </b><span id="Enemy level"></span>
                <br> <b>Health: </b><span id="Enemy health"></span>
                <br> <b>Stamina: </b><span id="Enemy stamina"></span>
                <br> <b>Armor: </b><span id="Enemy AC"></span>
                <br> <b>Weapon: </b><span id="Enemy weapon"></span>
                <br> <b>Action: </b><span id="Enemy action"></span>
     </div>

<div id="Container" align="center">
            <canvas id="healthButtonCanvas" class="containerButton"></canvas>
            <input type="button" alt="Health" id="Health button" class="containerButton" onclick="healthIncrease()">

            <canvas id="staminaButtonCanvas" class="containerButton"></canvas>
            <input type="button" alt="Stamina" id="Stamina button" class="containerButton" onclick="staminaIncrease()">

            <canvas id="defendButtonCanvas" class="containerButton"></canvas>
            <input type="button" alt="Defend" id="Defend button" class="containerButton" onclick="defend()">

            <canvas id="switchWeaponButtonCanvas" class="containerButton"></canvas>
            <input type="button" alt="Switch Weapon" id="Switch weapon button" class="containerButton" onclick="switchWeapon()">

            <canvas id="endTurnButtonCanvas" class="containerButton"></canvas>
            <input type="button" value="End Turn" id="End turn button" class="containerButton" onclick="endTurnButton()">
</div>

</div> <!-- Close the main div -->

<div id = "Test" align="center" class = "test"></div>

<div id="Text area" align="left">
    <p id="Result">Loading...</p>
    <canvas id="messageLogButtonCanvas"></canvas>
    <input type="button" value="Message Log" id="Message log button" class="message" onclick="messageLog()">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried binding an `.onload` handler to the img element before setting its `src`?

Comment: Maybe the images are already loaded so the load event wont be triggered. `gv.spriteSheet.complete` will tell you if the image is already loaded.

Comment: Hi Musa, I quickly tried:

if (gv.spriteSheet.complete) {
    // do all the stuff in the gv.spriteSheet.onload function
}

else {
    gv.spriteSheet.onload = function() {
        // run the gv.spriteSheet.onload function
    }
}

But that yielded exactly the same results. I'm guessing then it's not because the sprite sheet has already loaded.

Comment: Hi nnnnnn, not exactly sure what you mean. Would you mind providing a small code sample to explain? Also, how do you think this will help?

Comment: please post your full html src

Comment: OK tuan huynh, posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may seem absurd.. but you can try this:

```
 gv.spriteSheet.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
          drawArenaFloor();
          drawUnderlay();
          drawArenaWalls();
        },500);
    }
```

I have came out of these issues in IE many times using the timeout, seems as if IE handles events some other way.

Comment: That worked! How annoying - any idea why IE behaves in this way? The interesting thing is that now the images all load correctly in all browsers, but IE still lags before it starts playing sounds by about 5 seconds. I guess I'll have to add a similar delay to the sound loading functions. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Yes... similar feelings always for IE.. I think it just binds the handler to the onload.. and calls it with its own weird methodology.. but it does work always using the trick.. If it worked, atleast upvote the post, it might help others. :)

Comment: Thanks very much. Have flagged this as the correct answer as it does work in IE (I don't have enough rep to upvote yet). Now I just need to solve the IE audio delay problem :)

Comment: Thanks.. yes you can try them the similar way.. if it does not, please do mention how you got it working(hoping soon)..

Comment: Will do. I'm going to experiment with the canplaythrough event and post my results here.

Comment: Using `setTimeout` is obviously a non deterministic solution. There are better options such a inverting the order of statements. If you attach a listener **before** setting the `src` property the listener is executed correctly.